# Free / OpenSource Java Rules / Workflow engine

Tags: java, workflow, rules

I am looking for a Java Rules / Workflow engine. Something similar to Microsoft Workflow Engine.

Can someone recommend a product?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://java-source.net/open-source/rule-engines) is a rundown of many open-source Java rules engines including the usual suspects like [Drools](http://drools.org/), etc.

Answer (score 2):

- [jBPM](http://www.jboss.com/products/jbpm): aimed at business processes mostly;
- [OSWorkflow](http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/documentation.action): pretty low-level; and
- [Spring Webflow](http://www.springsource.org/webflow): not a generic workflow engine but a notworthy product if you ever need to implemented a flow-based Web application.

Nothing quite up there with WWF.

Answer (score 0):

CloudSlang : http://www.cloudslang.io/
codebase can be found here: https://github.com/CloudSlang